# In SpriteKit SKPhysicsContactDelegate contact is not detected

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicscontact

I am trying to program a game with Spritekit in Swift. The aim is to escape with his character oncoming rectangles. Now I've made a mistake with the SKPhysicsContactDelegate (didBegin ()) method, so the figure's contact with one of the rectangles is not recognized. Can someone help me find the mistake?

```
    import SpriteKit

enum bodyType: UInt32 {
    case rechteckRechts = 1
    case rechteckLinks = 2
    case figur = 4
}

class PlayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let figur = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Punkt.jpg")

    @objc func addRechteck(){
        let rechteckRechts = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rechteck.gif")
        rechteckRechts.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
        rechteckRechts.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        rechteckRechts.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bodyType.rechteckRechts.rawValue

        let rechteckLinks = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rechteck.gif")
        rechteckLinks.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
        rechteckLinks.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        rechteckLinks.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bodyType.rechteckLinks.rawValue

        let groesse = arc4random_uniform(5)+1
        print(groesse)

        switch groesse {
        case 1:
            rechteckLinks.xScale = 0.5
            rechteckRechts.xScale = 1.5
        case 2:
            rechteckLinks.xScale = 1.5
            rechteckRechts.xScale = 0.5
        case 3:
            rechteckLinks.xScale = 1
            rechteckRechts.xScale = 1
        case 4:
            rechteckLinks.xScale = 1.25
            rechteckRechts.xScale = 0.75
        case 5:
            rechteckLinks.xScale = 0.75
            rechteckRechts.xScale = 1.25
        default:
            print("Fehler in der Wahrscheinlichkeit!!!")
        }
        rechteckRechts.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX + (rechteckRechts.size.width / 2), y: frame.maxY)
        rechteckLinks.position = CGPoint(x: frame.maxX - (rechteckLinks.size.width / 2), y: frame.maxY)

        let moveDown = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -5000, duration: 20.0)
        rechteckLinks.run(moveDown)
        rechteckRechts.run(moveDown)

        self.addChild(rechteckRechts)
        self.addChild(rechteckLinks)
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        physicsWorld.gravity = .zero
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        figur.xScale = 0.4
        figur.yScale = 0.4
        figur.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY / 4)
        figur.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
        figur.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        figur.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bodyType.figur.rawValue
        self.addChild(figur)

        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.white

        let wait1 = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3)
        let timer = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([wait1, SKAction.run {
            self.addRechteck()
            }]))
        self.run(timer, withKey: "addRechteck")

    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

        switch contactMask {
        case bodyType.figur.rawValue | bodyType.rechteckLinks.rawValue:
            print("contact")
        case bodyType.figur.rawValue | bodyType.rechteckRechts.rawValue:
            print("contact")
        default:
            return
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in (touches ){
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            if figur.contains(location){
                figur.position = location
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in (touches ) {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            if figur.contains(location){
                figur.position = location
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set your contactTest bit masks?

Comment: No, I did not. How can I do it?.

Comment: Ok - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t appear to have set the collision and contactTest bit masks. These are properties of the physics body. The `collisionBitMask` controls which objects bounce off which other objects. By default, everything bounces off everything else.

The `contactTestBitMask` is the important one in this siutuation, as it controls which objects invoke ‘didBegin‘ when contacting other objects.  By default, this is 0 which means that no contacts are registered. See my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40596890/1430420 for a detailed explanation.

In your specific example, you appear to want to know when `figur` makes contact with either `rechteckLinks` or `rechteckRechts`, so you would want to following `contactTestBitMasks`:

```
figur.physicsBody!.cagegoryBitMask = bodyType.figur
figur.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = bodyType.rechteckRechts | bodyType.rechteckLinks
```

Edit: correcting the definition of `figur`s physics body:

We change the ? to ! so that we get a crash should the physics body not exist. We also change the `isDynamic` property to `true` as physics bodies that are not dynamic cannot register contacts (I think). It’s ok for the other 2 to not be dynamic. We assign the `collisionTestBitMask` to the value of all the categories we want to be notified of collision with logically ‘OR’ed together:

```
figur.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true 
figur.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = bodyType.figur.rawValue
figur.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = bodyType.rechteckRechts.rawValue | bodyType.rechteckLinks.rawValue
```

Comment: this probably sounds very stupid but it does not work. would it be possible that you supplement the code from above with your proposal and then send me?